# How to select an element with specific css value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to select an element if it has a css as display block then do this function. If the element has  the css as display block then remove ('hide') class from the header class.. This is what I want to do.. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are two solutions depending on what you want:

**Solution 1**

Looping through all elements and removing hide class from the current element if it has display block value in its style.

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

for(let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if(elements[i].style.display == "block") {
        elements[i].classList.remove("hide");
    }
}
```

**Solution 2**

Getting the reference of the element via HTML id.

```js
var element = document.getElementById("YourElementID");

if(element.style.display == "block") {
    element.classList.remove("hide");
}
```

You can define an id like this in your HTML file:

```html
 <div id="YourElementID">Div</div>
```

***I am assuming that you want to determine if the element has the "hide" class by checking its display style. you don't need to do that, you can easily check its class list by using the following code:***

```js
element.classList.contains("hide");
```

Comment: You're making it way too complex. If you are going to use JavaScript then just use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Comment: @Yogi I tried to help him, I am sorry i tried to simplify it as much as i can but I think I misunderstood the problem

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to sound harsh.  This is a good answer because you also remove the class.  Yet, getComputedStyle is good to know about as styles may be applied from many sources. +1

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of collecting all the elements with `display: block` and i am not sure, which one performs best - or whether it performs good at all.

If you want all the `Element` instances of the page, which have a computed style of `display: block` you can do something like:

```js
var $els = Array.from(document.body.querySelectorAll('*')).filter(function($el) {
    return getComputedStyle($el).display === 'block';
});
```

Or ES6:

```js
const $els = Array.from(document.body.querySelectorAll('*')).filter($el => getComputedStyle($el).display === 'block');
```

If you want the `Element` instances which have `display: block` literally set in the `style`-attribute, you have to do something like this:

```js
var $els = Array.from(document.body.querySelectorAll('*')).filter(function($el) {
    return $el.style.display === 'block';
});
```

I think it would perform better, if the selector in `querySelectorAll()` would be a little more specific.

Another option would be to use the [TreeWalker API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker), but then you have to do a mutation, because you have to iterate over all the elements and push them to an array:

```js
var $els = [];
walker = document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT);
while (walker.nextNode()) {
    if (getComputedStyle(walker.currentNode).display === 'block') {
        $els.push(walker.currentNode);
    }
}
```

Once you have all your elements, you can do something with them.

A little bit more information would be helpful, especially what exactly you want to achieve, once you have the elements, because then i could also provide more help. Maybe provide a code example?

Comment: This is a good start, but the question ask how to remove the .hide class when it contains a block element.  So we don't need to find all block elements, but just one and then remove the class if found. +1

Comment: OK. Can you give a simple HTML example of a possible structure? Because until now i did not fully understand, what you want to achieve. :-)